# Azure Cosmos DB sql join and udf

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I have below structure in cosmosdb

```
{"id": "8d4eecba-49fa-4707-979c-c9132b0c466b",
    "district": null,
    "course": null,
    "teachers": [],
    "created": "2018-08-14T14:25:41.1061235Z",
    "students": [
        "2e735887-ee17-435d-afd1-ac161ef7996e",
        "fbf477b1-bd34-42af-8b4b-876190d07aa9",
        "a4756841-2bb7-4ac1-8409-b1e382060b24",
        "29bdca72-2375-4bc5-8fc5-239f60985425",
        "eb9e456d-0407-4649-b67a-397e62339ebf",
        ],
    "teacher": "8e8bc2e7-63ad-4e27-98ed-5570d2f320ac",
    "subject": null,
    "_ts": 1555562226
}
```

from the above I want to get a list like below , is there any straight way ?

```
id                                             students
8d4eecba-49fa-4707-979c-c9132b0c466b           2e735887-ee17-435d-afd1-ac161ef7996e
8d4eecba-49fa-4707-979c-c9132b0c466b           fbf477b1-bd34-42af-8b4b-876190d07aa9
8d4eecba-49fa-4707-979c-c9132b0c466b           a4756841-2bb7-4ac1-8409-b1e382060b24
8d4eecba-49fa-4707-979c-c9132b0c466b           29bdca72-2375-4bc5-8fc5-239f60985425
8d4eecba-49fa-4707-979c-c9132b0c466b           eb9e456d-0407-4649-b67a-397e62339ebf
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use sql:

```
Select c.id,s 
from c
join s in c.students
```

Result:

```
[
    {
        "id": "8d4eecba-49fa-4707-979c-c9132b0c466b",
        "s": "2e735887-ee17-435d-afd1-ac161ef7996e"
    },
    {
        "id": "8d4eecba-49fa-4707-979c-c9132b0c466b",
        "s": "fbf477b1-bd34-42af-8b4b-876190d07aa9"
    },
    {
        "id": "8d4eecba-49fa-4707-979c-c9132b0c466b",
        "s": "a4756841-2bb7-4ac1-8409-b1e382060b24"
    },
    {
        "id": "8d4eecba-49fa-4707-979c-c9132b0c466b",
        "s": "29bdca72-2375-4bc5-8fc5-239f60985425"
    },
    {
        "id": "8d4eecba-49fa-4707-979c-c9132b0c466b",
        "s": "eb9e456d-0407-4649-b67a-397e62339ebf"
    }
]
```